# Find and replace text in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a task list for our department. 
The workbook is build up of the following sheets:

```
Master task list
Person A
Person B
Person C
```

When a new task (column C) is assigned to a person that will be automatically copied to the bottom of that persons task list. 
When the person is executing his / her task they will enter comments in the column comments (column M) and the progress in the column % (Column K).

I would like to create a VBA script that with one click of a button all the comments and progressions entered are updated in the master task list sheet.

I've tried various code (.find ; =address ; Match). and could not get any of the codes working.
My head is spinning now :-(

Can anyone please help me.

The number of tasks vary as well as the location in the master task list sheet (New tasks are entered at the top of the sheet).

Thank you

Comment: I want a VBA script, that updates the master task list with one click of a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a command button that has the following VBA text behind it.

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim nextrow As Long, i As Integer
Dim comments As String, task As String, progress As Double
Dim w10 As Worksheet, w20 As Worksheet
Dim sourcebook As Workbook
Dim findrow As Long, findcolumn As Long

Set sourcebook = ActiveWorkbook
Set w10 = sourcebook.Sheets("Master task list")
Set w20 = sourcebook.Sheets("Harsh C")

nextrow = w20.Range("C" & w20.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("M14", "M" & nextrow).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

For i = 14 To nextrow
    comments = w20.Cells(i, 13).Value
    progress = w20.Cells(i, 11).Value
    task = w20.Cells(i, 3).Value
    findrow = w10.Cells.Find(what:=task, MatchCase:=True).Row
    w10.Cells(findrow, 13).Value = comments
    w10.Cells(findrow, 11).Value = progress
On Error Resume Next
    Cells(i, 13).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Iv'e created two strings that capture the changes that need to be copied to the master task list. 
The i look up the unique task description on the master task list (.find) and return the row number where the task is found. 
Then i replace the existing progress and comments to the new progress and comments.

The coloring of the cells i've only done to show the user that Excel is performing the update task.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already build this part:

> When a new task (column C) is assigned to a person that will be automatically copied to the bottom of that persons task list

All you would need to do is add a task ID to the master list and reference this from each sheet with a vlookup and maybe an indirect.

If your master list has the Person the task is assigned to this formula will go in D2 on the master list:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!B1:Z10000"),10,FALSE)
```

Where:

- A2 is the Task ID on the Master List
- B2 is the The Sheet Name/Person (e.g Person A)
- The Range B1:Z10000 is the lookup range on the Person Sheet
- The number 10 is the relative distance between the ID field and Comments on the Person sheet with the column B containing the Task ID.

Sheet: Master List
A..............B.................C..............D....................E
Task ID....Person....... New Task..Percentage…Comments
1..............Person A.... Task 1...... 70................. Person A Comm 1
2..............Person B.... Task 2...... 12................. Person B TestComment 1
3..............Person C.... Task 3...... 34................. Person C TestComm 1
4..............Person A.... Task 4...... 23................. Person A Comm 2
5..............Person B.... Task 5...... 41................. Person B TestComment 2
6..............Person C.... Task 6...... 26................. Person C TestComm 2

Sheet: Person A
B............C............K...................M
Task ID..Task...... Progress %.. Comments
1............Task 1... 70................. Person A Comm 1
4............Task 4... 23................. Person A Comm 2

Sheet: Person B
B............C............K......................M
Task ID..Task...... Progress %..... Comments
2............Task 2... 12.................... Person B TestComment 1
5............Task 5... 41.................... Person B TestComment 2

Sheet: Person C
B............C............K...................M
Task ID..Task...... Progress %.. Comments
3............Task 3... 34................. Person C TestComm 1
6............Task 6... 26................. Person C TestComm 2

The indirect is a way of referencing another cell without explicitly stating it by creating a string of that reference.

So if B2 = Person A

The formula would resolve to:

=VLOOKUP(A2,'Person A'!B1:Z10000,10,FALSE)

Comment: The =vlookup function did not work for me, since the cells are dynamic. New lines are inserted on top of the list, so i would every time need to alter the vlookup function.  Thank though